# How to configure k8s nginx external auth and exclude health check path?

Tags: nginx, monitoring, kubernetes, uptime

We started using [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) as external authentication for some of our cluster infrastructure components.

Our cluster is using the [ingress-nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and the Ingress resources are configured following this [guide](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/configuration#configuring-for-use-with-the-nginx-auth_request-directive) here to use the external authentication.

Now my problem is that we use StatusCake to monitor uptime for the infrastructure components. It works when using basic authentication, but I have no idea how to configure it to report correctly when the component is behind the oauth2 authentication.

I was thinking to maybe exclude one path from external authentication (e.g. health check), but I cannot find any options to do so.

Another option would be to have an extra ingress for only a certain path, which seems overkill.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already tried creating a new `Ingress`, protected by Basic, for the health check URI?

Comment: No, that is another option of course. I was hoping for a solution without creating additional Ingress though.